# How to upload Image using Meteror CollectionFS to server Folder

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

i'm new to meteor. And i found that there are lost of option available for image storing. And finally i decided to use this package

[CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). 
But in this package it stores file in collection. I do not want to store image in collection , i just want to upload it in my server folder.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, this is possible! Please refer to the documentation:

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

In the Storage Adapter section is refers to cfs:filesystem. This allows you to save to the servers filesystem rather than a collection via GridFS. The Adapter and its documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/devel/packages/filesystem

The implementation is fairly straight forward with the documentation.

As it points out in the documentation, you can add something like this to your common.js file:

```
var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

This creates an FS.Collection called images which stores the images to a folded called uploads in your project and creates a collection to tie those uploads to. Structucing your project is a bit outside of the scope of your question, but you can get more information about that here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: for the filesystem they have given Uses but they do not specify where to write this code. Could you please help?

Comment: ok, i have created common.js , can it be written in my upload button event? 'click #uploadTest':function(){}

Comment: Yes :) check the documentation for "Initiate the Upload" and it should show you how.

Comment: i have written this code in my button click event var file = $('#testImage').get(0).files[0]; var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
                stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "myphotos"})]
            }); code doesn't give error and creates folder myphotos but there is no images in this folder, can you help?